# How to create an expandable <li> element in html

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I have this competetion about creating a website and I want to create a list element which is expandable when the user for example sends the mouse over it just like in the website below and the options pop out

http://www.howtogeek.com/

This is the HTML

```
<ul>
     <li><a href="articles.html">Artikuj</a></li>
     <li><a href="subscribe.html">Na ndiqni</a></li>
     <li><a href="about.html">Rreth nesh</a></li>
</ul>
```

And this is the CSS

```
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: black;
  height: 37px;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

li {
  float: left;
  font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: black
}

li a:hover:not(.active) {
  background-color: gray;
}

li a.active {
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Pure CSS:**

```css
ul {
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
overflow: hidden;
border: 1px solid black;
background-color: black;
height: 37px;
border-radius: 20px;
}

li {
float: left;
font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif
}

li a {
display: block;
color: white;
text-align: center;
padding: 14px 16px;
text-decoration: none;
background-color: black
}

li a:hover:not(.active) {
background-color: gray;
}

li a.active {
color: white;
background-color: black;
} 

li ul {
  display: none;
      position: absolute;
}

li:hover ul {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul>
     <li><a href="articles.html">Artikuj</a>
<ul>
     <li><a href="articles.html">Artikuj</a></li>
     <li><a href="subscribe.html">Na ndiqni</a></li>
     <li><a href="about.html">Rreth nesh</a></li>
</ul>
     </li>
     <li><a href="subscribe.html">Na ndiqni</a></li>
     <li><a href="about.html">Rreth nesh</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

**CSS:**

```
ul {
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
        background-color: #333;
    }

    li {
        float: left;
    }

    li a, .dropbtn {
        display: inline-block;
        color: white;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 14px 16px;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    li a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
        background-color: red;
    }

    li.dropdown {
        display: inline-block;
    }

    .dropdown-content {
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        background-color: #f9f9f9;
        min-width: 160px;
        box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    }

    .dropdown-content a {
        color: black;
        padding: 12px 16px;
        text-decoration: none;
        display: block;
        text-align: left;
    }
    li .menuall{
        width: 600px;
    }
    .menuall_list{
        float: left; 
        width: 200px;
    }
    .dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

    .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
        display: block;
    }
```

**HTML:**

```
<ul>
      <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropbtn">Artikuj</a>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
            <div class="menuall">
                <div class="menuall_list">
                  <a href="#">Link 1</a>
                  <a href="#">Link 2</a>
                  <a href="#">Link 3</a>
                </div>
                <div class="menuall_list">
                  <a href="#">Link 1</a>
                  <a href="#">Link 2</a>
                  <a href="#">Link 3</a>
                </div>
                <div class="menuall_list">
                  <a href="#">Link 1</a>
                  <a href="#">Link 2</a>
                  <a href="#">Link 3</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

This code is for as like [www.howtogeek.com](http://wwwhowtogeek.com) menu. Now you change the color or shape as per your design.